# Two questions on Flink externalized checkpoints

Tags: apache-flink

I have two questions on Flink externalized checkpoints

(Q1) I can set "state.checkpoints.dir" in flink-conf.yaml to get externalized checkpoints to work all right, but how do I achieve same thing when I run flink from IDE? I tried the GlobalConfiguration approach mentioned in (http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/state-checkpoints-dir-td17921.html) but no luck. This is how I did it:

```
Configuration cfg =
                GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration();
cfg.setString("state.checkpoints.dir", "file:///tmp/checkpoints/state");
env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

and this is the error msg show in IDE:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Failed to submit job ef7050e2308a4787d983d80f3c07f55c (Long Taxi Rides (checkpointed))
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:447)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:38)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:122)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CheckpointConfig says to persist periodic checkpoints, but no checkpoint directory has been configured. You can configure configure one via key 'state.checkpoints.dir'.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:211)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.enableCheckpointing(ExecutionGraph.java:478)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:291)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1277)
    ... 19 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(Q2) In the checkpoint's document (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html), it says "This way, you will have a checkpoint around to resume from if your job fails.", how about the cancelled jobs? will the new job carry on with the existing checkpoint or it will start with its own checkpoint?

Answer (score 4):

You can control whether externalized checkpoints are deleted when the job is cancelled. If you want to retain them, you can do this:

```
CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

For more info, see [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/checkpoints.html#externalized-checkpoints).

To [resume from an externalized checkpoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/state/checkpoints.html#resuming-from-an-externalized-checkpoint) one does this (the same as resuming from a savepoint):

```
$ bin/flink run -s :checkpointMetaDataPath [:runArgs]
```

Comment: Thanks Dave - I forgot that deleting the checkpoint on cancel is only the default behavior, and can be configured differently.

Comment: Does flink adds this checkpointMetaDataPath automatically when I cancel and start my application again from flink ui ?

When resuming from command, this should work:
bin/flink run -s :checkpointMetaDataPath [:runArgs]

Comment: @David Anderson Do we have any way to automatic resume from checkpoint stored in S3? It becomes tricky as -s :checkpointMetaDataPath needs to have job_id of flink and to find out this job id at tun time?

Comment: @UmeshK Flink normally resumes from checkpoints automatically. And starting from a savepoint or externalized checkpoint does not require a job_id. So I don't understand your question -- can you ask a new question, and provide more details about what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

First question,create a local environment with custom config:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.setString(CoreOptions.CHECKPOINTS_DIRECTORY, "file:///user/flink/checkpoint/storing/")
StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(4, conf)
```

Second question, as David said:

```
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

Re setting the checkpoint directory from Eclipse, normally I just do it when setting up the backend to use, e.g.

```
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend(options.getCheckpointDir()));
```

Re cancelled jobs - the checkpoint directory gets removed. You need to do a savepoint if you want to resume from a known state after stopping (cancelling) your job.

Comment: options is just my own class with command line parameter values. You can pass any valid path (file:///xxx is typical when running from Eclipse) to the FsStateBackend constructor.