# Apache Flink : How to configure savepoint directory in java program?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Can I configure a different savepoint path for the different job in flink?

I found one configuration ***`state.savepoints.dir`*** under `flink-conf.yaml` file but that is applied to all jobs. so I can not differentiate the savepoint state for a particular job.

Is there any way to configure that path in Flink's Java Program?

Comment: I try to use setDefaultSavepointDirectory to set savepoint directory, but the local flink cluster throws "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The configuration is unmodifiable; its contents cannot be changed."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can set this in Java, but you can specify a directory when executing the savepoint command.

Note that savepoints are saved under a job-id sub-dir inside of the savepoint directory, so they are differentiated even if you're using the default directory set up in flink-conf.yaml

Comment: I am looking for external check point which has retain on cancellation policy. Can I do?

Comment: Regarding retain on cancel - yes, see discussion here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719224/231762